# Why doesn't the query time appear when counting rows with COUNT()?

Tags: mysql, benchmarking, database-performance, query-performance

It doesn't seem to matter whether my query has any clauses in it or not (e.g. `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, etc), but I just noticed (after having worked with MySQL for quite some time) that anytime I add `COUNT()` to my `SELECT` statement, the text at the top that displays the query time just kind of "goes away".

Examples:

1. MySQL result *with* query time displayed:

   [image: MySQL result with query time displayed]
2. MySQL result *without* query time displayed (after adding `COUNT`):

   [image: MySQL result without query time displayed]

Note that in the first example it says `( Query took 0.0003 sec )`, whereas in the second example it does not. Why is this? And is there a way to force the query time to appear (e.g. for benchmarking purposes)?

Comment: The time appeared in both cases when I tried it (HeidiSQL on MySQL 5.5.21). It probably depends on what client/api you are using.

Comment: Try sqlyog and it works fine